# Constructor.newInstance replaces Scala object

Tags: scala, reflection

I was debugging a deserialization issue with Jackson where Scala `object` instances seemed to be replaced. I managed to drill the issue down to this code:

```
object WaitWhat extends App {

  object XX

  val x1 = XX

  // Notice: no assignment!
  XX.getClass.getConstructor().newInstance()

  val x2 = XX

  println(x1)
  println(x2)
}
```

The output is:

```
WaitWhat$XX$@5315b42e
WaitWhat$XX$@2ef9b8bc
```

(Of course the actual hash codes change each run.)

IntelliJ's debugger also indicates that `x1` and `x2` really are different instances, despite the fact that the result of `newInstance` is completely ignored.

I would have expected a no-op, or an exception of some kind. How is it possible that the actual object instance gets *replaced* by this call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objects in Scala have a private constructor that can’t be called with new (since it’s private), but can still be called using reflection.

Under the hood, the object is accessed by static `MODULE$` field. This field is the singleton instance created internally by calling the private constructor.

As long as you access the object in your Scala or in your Java code using `MODULE$` you will be ok. However, you can't be sure, that some library won't create an additional instance of your object with a private constructor using reflection. In this case, whenever private constructor will be called, a new instance of the object will be created and reassigned to `MODULE$`.

This can happen especially if you use Java libraries, that are not aware of the existence of Scala objects.

Please check this [article](https://blog.softwaremill.com/is-your-scala-object-always-a-singleton-cb3fd24a2fd9) for more details.

Anyway, I would just create custom deserializer for Jackson (similarly to the solution described in the article).

Comment: And the final piece of the puzzle, from your article: "the MODULE$ static field is initialized every time the private constructor is called"

Comment: Great to hear that :)